Excel Code running twice unintendedly when A checkbox is added to Chain code together
I have a few blocks of codes, made to assist a user to automate defect capturing. I have a userform, and that form has a listbox called ScreeningDefectList. I have a button called Fail and a box called SelectedDefect. When user selects an item in ScreeningDefectList, the SelectedDefect gains the value of the list index (lets say list index of 1 is a cut, then SelectedDefect will have the text "Cut").
The button "Fail" then places the SelectedDefectValue into a cell, then updates the ScreeningDefectList (The list has 3 columns and the last column has the qty).
I added a checkbox called OneClickToFail, which when checked, causes the action of clicking on a defect in the list to also call the "Fail" button, turning the 2 click process into a 1 click process.
However, now the ScreeningDefectList_Click() Subroutine gets executed twice without any clear explanation. When executing in step mode, I see that the ScreeningDefectList_Click() Subroutine goes all the way to the end and then goes back to the start of this "Private Sub ScreeningDefectList_Click()" again.
I want to ask if anyone knows how to stop this from happening?
I have tried to put in some exit subs and it did not work because as soon as it exits the sub, it goes back to the "Private Sub ScreeningDefectList_Click()" line.
Attaching the related codes here. Note that this executes twice, exactly 2 times. I need it to execute once only
This one is the problematic code
Private Sub ScreeningDefectList_Click() 'Loops Back here when exit sub or end sub is reached

'puts the defect reason in a textbox for later reference
SelectedDefect.Value = ScreeningDefectList.List(ScreeningDefectList.ListIndex, 1)

'Checks if the tick box "One Click To Fail" is checked and if so it will also execute Fail_Click
If OneClickToFail.Value = True Then

    Call Fail_Click
    
    Exit Sub
    
Else: Exit Sub

End If

Exit Sub 'Did not work

End Sub 'Loops to the top


If the Tickbox OneClickToFail is checked, it will Execute this code too

Private Sub Fail_Click()

'If part is fail, then this fails the part and will input the reason instead of just "fail". anything that is not a Pass is a Fail based on the formula on spreadsheet

'Makes sure that a defect is selected first
If SelectedDefect.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please Select a Defect from the List"
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim currentcolumnindex As Integer

'this block makes sure that WIP info is filled in, otherwise will prevent the buttons being clicked
If WIPWO.TextLength < 7 And WIPWO.Value <> "-" Then
    MsgBox "Please Enter Valid Work Order Number or Put a - "
    Exit Sub
End If

If WIPBatch.TextLength < 1 And WIPBatch.Value <> "-" Then
    MsgBox "Please Enter Valid Batch Number or Put a - "
    Exit Sub
End If

If WIPCTRL.TextLength < 10 And WIPCTRL.Value <> "-" Then
    MsgBox "Please Enter Valid Control Number or Put a - "
    Exit Sub
End If

If WIPBatchID.TextLength < 8 And WIPBatchID.Value <> "-" Then
    MsgBox "Please Enter Valid Batch ID or Put a - "
    Exit Sub
End If

If WIPOriginalQty.TextLength < 1 Or IsNumeric(WIPOriginalQty) = False Then
    MsgBox "Please Enter Valid Original Qty for this Batch "
    Exit Sub
End If

'inputs the reason and moves down one cell
ActiveCell.Value = SelectedDefect.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

'these refreshes the userform with the latest information.
Call FillInInspectionInfo 'makes sure inspection info is updated
Call UpdateDefectCount 'updates count on column P
Call PopulateScreeningDefects 'updates the list on userform
Call ContinueInspectionInfo 'makes sure inspection info is reflected on userform

currentcolumnindex = ActiveCell.Column

WIPPassQty = Cells(8, currentcolumnindex).Value
WIPFailQty = Cells(9, currentcolumnindex).Value

SelectedDefect.Value = ""

'saves the file. the philosophy is to save every button click
'ThisWorkbook.Save

'this is for the undo function
LastFilledRowsCount = 1


End Sub


Fail_Click Calls this code
Private Sub FillInInspectionInfo()

'Checks that there isn't information in the column's WIP information table already, then if not it will fill in the information
'Good practice to check constantly, also allows any ammendments if necessary
Dim currentcolumnindex As Integer
currentcolumnindex = ActiveCell.Column

If Cells(2, currentcolumnindex).Value = "" Then
    Cells(2, currentcolumnindex).Value = WIPWO.Value
End If

If Cells(3, currentcolumnindex).Value = "" Then
    Cells(3, currentcolumnindex).Value = WIPBatch.Value
End If

If Cells(4, currentcolumnindex).Value = "" Then
    Cells(4, currentcolumnindex).Value = WIPCTRL.Value
End If

If Cells(5, currentcolumnindex).Value = "" Then
    Cells(5, currentcolumnindex).Value = WIPBatchID.Value
End If

If Cells(6, currentcolumnindex).Value = "" Then
    Cells(6, currentcolumnindex).Value = WIPOriginalQty.Value
End If

End Sub


Fail Click also calls this code
Public Sub UpdateDefectCount()
'Updates the list on Column N

Dim iCol1 As String
Dim rngStart As String
Dim rngEnd As String
Dim LastDefectType As Integer
Dim DefectType As Integer

DefectType = 1

'gets the info for existing defect list
LastDefectType = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("N:N"))

'Remembers which column it is
currentcolumnindex = ActiveCell.Column
iCol1 = Left(Cells(1, currentcolumnindex).Address(False, False), 1)
'col2 = Left(Cells(1, currentcolumnindex - 1).Address(False, False), 1)i

'remembers the starting cell on row 13 and also end cell on row 4012. this is 4000 entries
rngStart = iCol1 & "13"
rngEnd = iCol1 & "4012"

'For each defect on the list, update the values on column P based on the category on column O
For DefectType = 1 To LastDefectType

Range("P" & DefectType + 2).Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(rngStart, rngEnd), Range("O" & DefectType + 2).Value)

Next DefectType

End Sub


Fail Click also calls this
Private Sub PopulateScreeningDefects()

'Refereshes the Defect List in the userform
Dim EndOfList As Integer

'Adding 2 rows because the list on column N to column P starts at row 3. it gets the max value and adds 2 to get the actual address
'Inefficient coding but this makes the coding a tiny bit simpler
EndOfList = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("N:N")) + 2

'Draws the table, it has 3 columns and the widths are defined below. Gets the string values from column N to P
With ScreeningDefectList
.ColumnCount = 3
.ColumnWidths = "35,350,60"
.List = Range("N3:P" & EndOfList).Value

End With

End Sub


Lastly This

Private Sub ContinueInspectionInfo()

'When you enter the form, these fill in the form any existing information that is already entered for the column
Dim currentcolumnindex As Integer
currentcolumnindex = ActiveCell.Column

WIPWO.Value = Cells(2, currentcolumnindex).Value
WIPBatch.Value = Cells(3, currentcolumnindex).Value
WIPCTRL.Value = Cells(4, currentcolumnindex).Value
WIPBatchID.Value = Cells(5, currentcolumnindex).Value
WIPOriginalQty.Value = Cells(6, currentcolumnindex).Value
WIPPassQty.Value = Cells(8, currentcolumnindex).Value
WIPFailQty = Cells(9, currentcolumnindex).Value
WIPInspectedQty.Value = Cells(10, currentcolumnindex).Value
WIPLeftoverQty.Value = Cells(11, currentcolumnindex).Value

End Sub



Tried to put exit subs but did not work

The line which is causing the problem is .List = Range("N3:P" & EndOfList).Value. This is causing the ScreeningDefectList_Click() to be executed again
Here is a basic example to reproduce your problem.
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    '~~> I hard coded this for testing
    ScreeningDefectList.ColumnWidths = "35,350,60"
    ScreeningDefectList.List = Range("N3:P9").Value
End Sub

Private Sub Fail_Click()
    MsgBox "This is message B"
    PopulateScreeningDefects
End Sub

Private Sub ScreeningDefectList_Click()  
    MsgBox "This is message A"
    
    If OneClickToFail.Value = True Then
        Fail_Click
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateScreeningDefects()
    With ScreeningDefectList
        .ColumnCount = 3
        .ColumnWidths = "35,350,60"
        '~~> I hard coded this for testing
        .List = Range("N3:P10").Value
    End With
End Sub

To solve this, use a boolean variable say DoNotExecute. Here is an example.
Option Explicit

Dim DoNotExecute As Boolean

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    '~~> I hard coded this for testing
    ScreeningDefectList.ColumnWidths = "35,350,60"
    ScreeningDefectList.List = Range("N3:P9").Value
End Sub

Private Sub Fail_Click()
    MsgBox "This is message B"
    PopulateScreeningDefects
End Sub

Private Sub ScreeningDefectList_Click()
    '~~> If you comment this If EndIF Block then
    '~~> ScreeningDefectList_Click will be executed again
    If DoNotExecute = True Then
        DoNotExecute = False
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    MsgBox "This is message A"
    
    If OneClickToFail.Value = True Then
        DoNotExecute = True
        Fail_Click
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateScreeningDefects()
    With ScreeningDefectList
        .ColumnCount = 3
        .ColumnWidths = "35,350,60"
        '~~> I hard coded this for testing
        .List = Range("N3:P10").Value
    End With
End Sub

In Action: Click me to see the animated gif.
